# .NET: Does ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow dissociate ThreadStatic variables?

Tags: .net, threadstatic

The title of the question pretty much says it all. Will static variables marked with the `[ThreadStaticAttribute]` get messed up if you use `ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()` to cancel the propagation of the security context and identity token, etc.?

In other words, are thread statics included in the set of context items? If so, is there a way to specify which parts of the context you want (i.e. only ThreadStatics and not the rest).

Comment: No.  What makes you think that?

Comment: Racking my brain about where I got this impression, I now remember that it was probably from Stephen Toub's excellent article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163644.aspx : "if nothing about the source thread is transferred to the target thread, the disconnect that occurs can lead to a variety of problems. Some of these problems lead to functional bugs, such as data stored in the source's thread-local storage not being available during execution..."

Comment: p.s. I did realize that that says TLS and not ThreadStatic, but it raised the possibility that the latter also might not be flowed..?

Comment: So... are ThreadStatic variables not TLS then?

Comment: @Brain2000 Not sure. Unfortunately, the link to Toub's article is now dead and I can't seem to refresh my memory about this issue :-(